# How do you import a maven EJB project in eclipse? (without m2e)

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, maven, ejb-3.0

I made an EJB project through Maven using "org.codehaus.mojo.archetypes:ejb-jee5" lastest version.

Then I typed "mvn install" and "mvn eclipse:eclipse".

Finally I imported it as a general java project in eclipse but the project is not being recognised as being EJB capable.

What did I do wrong?

Thanks

## EDIT

tried this as suggested by an awnser, doesn't work

```
<build>
    <plugins>   
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <buildcommands>
                    <buildcommand>org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.builder</buildcommand>
                    <buildcommand>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</buildcommand>
                    <buildcommand>org.eclipse.wst.validation.validationbuilder</buildcommand>
                </buildcommands>
                <additionalProjectnatures>
                    <projectnature>org.eclipse.jem.workbench.JavaEMFNature</projectnature>
                    <projectnature>org.eclipse.wst.common.modulecore.ModuleCoreNature</projectnature>
                    <projectnature>eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</projectnature>
                    <projectnature>org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.nature</projectnature>
                </additionalProjectnatures>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

## EDIT

Apparently adding those builder and natures to your .project is not enougth, an xml file describing wich facet is enabled must be generated too, in order to do that I should add the following code betwen the '' tags

```
<additionalProjectFacets>
    <jst.java>1.6</jst.java>
    <jst.ejb>3.0</jst.ejb>
</additionalProjectFacets>
```

However those 4 line generate a 'Build failure'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found out, as expected modifying the project natures is not enought, you also have to generate other file describing thing such as activated facets, etc.

add this to your EJB project and it will be recognized as an EJB without m2e.

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <additionalBuildcommands>
                        <buildCommand>
                            <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
                        </buildCommand>
                        <buildCommand>
                            <name>org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.builder</name>
                        </buildCommand>
                        <buildCommand>
                            <name>org.eclipse.wst.validation.validationbuilder</name>
                        </buildCommand>
                        <buildCommand>
                            <name>org.eclipse.ui.externaltools.ExternalToolBuilder</name>
                            <arguments>
                                <LaunchConfigHandle>&lt;project&gt;/.settings/MavenBuilder.launch</LaunchConfigHandle>
                            </arguments>
                        </buildCommand>
                    </additionalBuildcommands>
                    <additionalProjectnatures>
                        <projectnature>org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.nature</projectnature>
                        <projectnature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</projectnature>
                        <projectnature>org.eclipse.wst.common.modulecore.ModuleCoreNature</projectnature>
                        <projectnature>org.eclipse.jem.workbench.JavaEMFNature</projectnature>
                    </additionalProjectnatures>
                    <additionalConfig>
                        <file>
                            <name>.settings/org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml</name>
                            <content>
                                <![CDATA[<faceted-project>
    <runtime name="my JBoss Runtime" />
    <fixed facet="jst.ejb" />
    <fixed facet="jst.java" />
    <installed facet="jst.java" version="6.0" />
    <installed facet="jst.ejb" version="3.0" />
</faceted-project>]]>
                            </content>
                        </file>
                        <file>
                            <name>.settings/org.eclipse.wst.common.component</name>
                            <content>
                                <![CDATA[
<project-modules id="moduleCoreId" project-version="1.5.0">
    <wb-module deploy-name="${project.artifactId}">
        <wb-resource deploy-path="/" source-path="/src/main/java" />
        <wb-resource deploy-path="/" source-path="/src/main/resources" />
        <property name="java-output-path" value="target/classes" />
    </wb-module>
</project-modules>]]>
                            </content>
                        </file>
                        <file>
                            <name>.checkstyle</name>
                            <content>
                                <![CDATA[<fileset-config file-format-version="1.2.0" simple-config="true">
    <fileset name="all" enabled="true" check-config-name="Myproject Checks" local="false">
        <file-match-pattern match-pattern="." include-pattern="true" />
    </fileset>
</fileset-config>]]>
                            </content>
                        </file>
                        <file>
                            <name>.settings/MavenBuilder.launch</name>
                            <content>
                                <![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<launchConfiguration type="org.eclipse.ui.externaltools.ProgramBuilderLaunchConfigurationType">
<stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.debug.core.ATTR_REFRESH_SCOPE" value="$${working_set:&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot;?&gt;&#13;&#10;&lt;launchConfigurationWorkingSet editPageId=&quot;org.eclipse.ui.resourceWorkingSetPage&quot; factoryID=&quot;org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkingSetFactory&quot; label=&quot;working set&quot; name=&quot;working set&quot;&gt;&#13;&#10;&lt;item factoryID=&quot;org.eclipse.ui.internal.model.ResourceFactory&quot; path=&quot;/acces-services/target/test-classes&quot; type=&quot;2&quot;/&gt;&#13;&#10;&lt;item factoryID=&quot;org.eclipse.ui.internal.model.ResourceFactory&quot; path=&quot;/acces-services/target/classes&quot; type=&quot;2&quot;/&gt;&#13;&#10;&lt;/launchConfigurationWorkingSet&gt;}" />
<booleanAttribute key="org.eclipse.debug.core.capture_output" value="false" />
<booleanAttribute key="org.eclipse.debug.ui.ATTR_CONSOLE_OUTPUT_ON" value="false" />
<booleanAttribute key="org.eclipse.debug.ui.ATTR_LAUNCH_IN_BACKGROUND" value="false" />
<stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.ui.externaltools.ATTR_BUILD_SCOPE" value="$${working_set:&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot;?&gt;&#13;&#10;&lt;launchConfigurationWorkingSet editPageId=&quot;org.eclipse.ui.resourceWorkingSetPage&quot; factoryID=&quot;org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkingSetFactory&quot; label=&quot;workingSet&quot; name=&quot;workingSet&quot;&gt;&#13;&#10;&lt;item factoryID=&quot;org.eclipse.ui.internal.model.ResourceFactory&quot; path=&quot;/acces-services/src/test/resources&quot; type=&quot;2&quot;/&gt;&#13;&#10;&lt;item factoryID=&quot;org.eclipse.ui.internal.model.ResourceFactory&quot; path=&quot;/acces-services/src/main/resources&quot; type=&quot;2&quot;/&gt;&#13;&#10;&lt;/launchConfigurationWorkingSet&gt;}" />
<stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.ui.externaltools.ATTR_LOCATION" value="${env.M2_HOME}\bin\mvn.bat" />
<stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.ui.externaltools.ATTR_RUN_BUILD_KINDS" value="full,incremental,auto,clean" />
<stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.ui.externaltools.ATTR_TOOL_ARGUMENTS" value="resources:resources resources:testResources --offline" />
<booleanAttribute key="org.eclipse.ui.externaltools.ATTR_TRIGGERS_CONFIGURED" value="true" />
<stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.ui.externaltools.ATTR_WORKING_DIRECTORY" value="$${workspace_loc:/acces-services}" />
</launchConfiguration>]]>
                            </content>
                        </file>
                    </additionalConfig>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

notice that We are defining wich Server runtime is being used, meaning you have to configure a server runtime before and put it's name inside.

Answer (score 0):

you can add the needed nature (thats how its named in eclipse world) in pom.xml

See [Adding project nature to your Maven pom](http://vikashazrati.wordpress.com/2007/12/22/adding-project-nature-to-your-maven-pomxml/) to create an empty EJB project and see in .project how the nature is named (it might have more then one nature).

Comment: I edited my question to show you the code I putted into my pom.xml, undortunatly, it doesn't work.